# Levels of recursion in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

How do I determine how many levels of recursion are necessary for merge sort to sort a list of size 8?

I am looking for only the level of recursive calls, not the return steps.

will it be 4?

Because if I have a list: `{18,16,13,14,11,12,15,17}` I can sort it in 4 levels using recursion

```
{18,16,13,14,11,12,15,17}
```

one initial call, then a level of recursion for each time you need to divide the list in half before you get down to single-element lists.

```
{18,16,13,14} {11,12,15,17}
{18,16} {13,14} {11,12} {15,17}
{18} {16} {13} {14} {11} {12} {15} {17}
```

or `log2(n)` levels plus `1` = `log2(8) + 1` = `4`

Comment: yes, seems right.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the terms **level of recursion** precisely: it refers conventionally to the depth of recursion, but does the first call count? In your example, you show 3 levels of recursion, but the depth of the call stack is 4 including the initial call with the full array.

Furthermore, there would be an extra level if the array size was just one greater than `8`, which your formula would fail to account for.

Here is a more accurate algorithm, counting the initial call:

- if the length is 0 or 1, depth is 1
- otherwise, depth is 2 + log2(length - 1)